# heroku cli error: "fork: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: command-line-tool, heroku

How to resolve this error with Heroku's command-line interface:

```
-bash> heroku ps -a cool-app-name
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 12: cd: : No such file or directory
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 18: [: /Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin: unary operator expected
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 21: /node: No such file or directory
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 12: cd: : No such file or directory
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 18: [: /Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin: unary operator expected
/Users/billy/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 21: /node: No such file or directory
```

This happens no matter what `heroku` command I run... `ps`, `login`, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Actually, this solution only works for one or two runs of the command... after that it fails again in the same way. **Thus this is still an unsolved problem.**

**OLD ANSWER**

Move `~/.local/share/heroku`...

```
-bash> mv ~/.local/share/heroku ~/.local/share/heroku-
```

And then run the `heroku` tool again (it will take a moment to **reinstall** the CLI) and the problem should be resolved...

```
-bash> heroku ps -a cool-app-name
heroku-cli: Installing CLI... 22.43MB/22.43MB
=== web (1X): bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 3 --nginx-config-template config/nginx.conf.erb (1)
web.1: up 2017/06/29 13:29:58 -0700 (~ 2h ago)
```

You can probably remove `~/.local/share/heroku-` once you're comfortable that everything is working as you expect.